# Fire effect looks different when renderd

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing, effects, fire

Why when looking at the fire in the view port looks better than when its rendered? And if I want the fire just to be static (not an animation) what do I do?I just render it without baking?

Thanks

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please ask only one question in each post. To render a static frame you still need to cache the simulation at least one time. You might choose not to bake it and save it to disk, but that means that if you close and open the file again the simulation will need to be re-cached again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off I would disagree that the fire looks "better" in the viewport (but that is the very nature of using comparative and superlative adjectives to ask questions: at the end they are just opinions... Impossible to answer objectively...)

If the issue is how bright the fire is, there are many ways to control it.

The most obvious way is by increasing the intensity of the emission for the smoke domain.

[image]

It is very easy to push the values to the point where the brightest (hottest) part of the fire become white.

The issue becomes that the intensity of the emitter prevents us very quickly to deal with the color saturation in a way that resembles the images of fire that we are used to.

A different approach would be to change the intensity along with the way the values of the scene are mapped to create an image, so....

Welcome to the wonderful world of color management!

In this brave, and mostly unexplored world, you can have a lot more control on the intensity, and most importantly, how those values become the final image.

Given that you are exploring a version of blender that includes the filmic blender, you can find new ways to have intense values without having to loose detail in the bright areas.

[image]